# NullPointerException on not null object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have a strange problem: I'm debugging my application and I have this NullPointerException, but the object is not null.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.clh.model.margin.table.classes.ChMarginHeaderP.createCopy(Unknown Source)
    at com.clh.controller.builders.EccFirstCallBean.buildDefaultComponent(EccFirstCallBean.java:710)
    at com.clh.controller.builders.EccFirstCallBean.buildFirstCall(EccFirstCallBean.java:549)
    at com.clh.controller.builders.EccFirstCallBean.buildMargin(EccFirstCallBean.java:403)
    at com.clh.controller.builders.EccFirstCallBean.elabThirdLevel(EccFirstCallBean.java:268)
    at com.clh.controller.builders.EccFirstCallBeanTest.elabThirdLevelTest(EccFirstCallBeanTest.java:529)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:68)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:89)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:97)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:87)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:50)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

That's what is just before I press F5 to step into and getting the exception:
[image: Variable status before Exception]

This is the createCopyMethod:

```
public ChMarginHeaderP createCopy() {
        final ChMarginHeaderP copyChMarginHeaderP = new ChMarginHeaderP(
                new ChMarginHeaderPPK(1), this.flgLock,this.flgIsLive, 
                this.referenceDate, this.userDescription,
                this.chCounterpartyPk,
                this.chCurrencyPk, this.chTypePk,
                this.chPortfolioPk, this.chProductsPk, this.chEntitiesPk,
                this.chStatusTradePk, this.chTypeCalledPk,this.segment, this.class_, this.section, this.division);

        return copyChMarginHeaderP;
    }
```

The .super() method belongs to the Object class

```
public ChMarginHeaderP(final ChMarginHeaderPPK id, final boolean flgLock,
            final boolean flgLive, final Date referenceDate,
            final String userDescription, final String chCounterpartiesPk,
            final String chCurrenciesPk, final String chTypePk,
            final String chPortfolioPk, final String chProductsPk,
            final String chEntitiesPk, final String chStatusMargin,
            final String chTypeCalledPk, final String segment, 
            final String class_, final String section, final String division) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.flgLock = flgLock;
        this.flgIsLive = flgLive;
        this.referenceDate = referenceDate;
        this.userDescription = userDescription;
        this.chCounterpartyPk= chCounterpartiesPk;
        this.chCurrencyPk = chCurrenciesPk;
        this.chTypePk = chTypePk;
        this.chPortfolioPk = chPortfolioPk;
        this.chProductsPk = chProductsPk;
        this.chEntitiesPk = chEntitiesPk;
        this.chStatusTradePk = chStatusMargin;
        this.chTypeCalledPk = chTypeCalledPk;
        this.segment = segment;
        this.class_ = class_;
        this.section = section; 
        this.division = division;
    }
```

Why my debugger can't see the source code of the method? Which are the possible causes? "Add line number attribute..." is checked in Compiler options in Preferences. I'va also tried to remove all breakpoints, project clean, uncheck and then check the box but I can't.

Comment: then check where it is thrown originally. a NullPointerException only has one possible origin: an action taken on a not instantiated instance of a class

Comment: The exception happens somewhere within `ChMarginHeaderP.createCopy()`, but the sources of that are not available to the debugger, so it cannot give more details.

Comment: It is entirely possible that `ChMarginHeaderP.createCopy` itself has a line `throw new NullPointerException()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what library is `at com.clh.model.margin.table.classes.ChMarginHeaderP` from? I can't find anything about it, and the domain seems to be for sale...

Comment: That library is of my company

Comment: Why the source should not be available to the debugger?

Answer (score 4):

The first line of the stack trace is where the NPE is actually thrown. As you can see, it is **not** on the line you highlighted - that is where you call `createCopy()`, and that works fine (because `defaultChMarginHeaderP` is not null, as your debugger correctly tells you). It's some code *inside* the `createCopy()` call that is either explicitly throwing the exception (literally, `throw new NullPointerException()` is in that method and is being executed), or, some code in there that dereferences a null pointer. Usually something like `foo.methodCall()` where `foo` is `null`. What is that code? Dunno - you are running ChMarginHeaderP as a class file (not as a source file), and the class file does not have debug info, hence, unknown line number and all that.

Debugging this without such debug info means you have to read docs and toy around, figure out 'in the dark' what precondition requirement of the createCopy method you are violating.

Normally you have this info, which gives you a line number, that you can crosscheck with the source of ChMarginHeaderP and then you'll know much faster.